# How to Convert Time from 24 hour format to 12 hour format (AM/PM) with Pandas (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, format

I've read several posts already, but the solutions suggested do not help in my case. In my dataframe, I have a column titled"Time" with time range values such as "10:30:00-11:30:00". In order to convert the time appropriately, I figured it was best to split up the column into a "Start" and "End" column by the delimiter "-". Once done, I have tried to use the below on one column to get it to work:

```
df[['start', 'end']] = df.Time.str.split("-", expand = True)

df['start']  = datetime.strptime(df['start'], '%H:%M:%S')

print(df['start'].strftime('%I:%M %p'))
```

**Error Message:**

> TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series

Both "start" and "end" have a data type of object and from what I read strings and objects are basically one in the same.

I also tried:

```
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start']).datetime.strftime('%I:%M %p')
```

**Error Message:**

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'datetime'

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `.dt` instead of `.datetime` per your last line of code

```
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start']).dt.strftime('%I:%M %p')
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "format" argument in pd.to_datetime.
IE

```
pd.to_datetime(df['start'], format='%I:%M %p')
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior